# GitGutter sign not working

Tags: git, signs

I have [`airblade/vim-gitgutter`](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter) installed via Vundle. Somehow even with minimal `.vimrc` `vim-gitgutter` signs aren't working. My minimal `.vimrc` is given below, is there any problem there? Any help will be appreciated.

```
set number relativenumber
set updatetime=1000

filetype off

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()


Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'airblade/vim-gitgutter'

call vundle#end()
filetype indent plugin on
```

Edit: I have edited `.vimrc`; `:PluginList` shows `Vundle` and `vim-gitgutter`. `echo g:loaded_gitgutter` gives 1 and `echo exists(':GitGutterToggle')` gives 2. Still signs aren't working.

Comment: That is not a minimal vimrc. You need to create a vimrc with only the lines relevant to the plugin installation. So remove the highlighting groups, your `GitStatus` function, get rid of `nocompatible` (just because it's useless if you have a vimrc). Then show us what `:PluginList` returns to make sure you actually installed the plugin. Then show us what `echo g:loaded_gitgutter` and `echo exists(':GitGutterToggle')` returns to see if it's only the signs which don't work or the plugin which is not loaded.

Comment: Then try to follow what [`:h sign-commands`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/sign.txt.html#sign-commands) says to place a sign by yourself to see if the issue comes from the plugin or from your setup which can't show any sign. Also we need to make sure that you are in a directory holding an actual git repo with some unchecked changes otherwise there is no signs to display. Basically help us to help you, give us relevant information otherwise it is impossible to debug your config for you.

Comment: @statox I have edited my question and added information.

Comment: so what do you expect from this vimrc when signs should appear?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I expect signs to appear, but I don't understand why that's not happening despite these echo results.

Comment: @MahbubAlam You know, that this happens only, once you change a file, that is been tracked in a git repository?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Signs aren't supposed to work for all files!? Only for files in a git repo?

Comment: @MahbubAlam Oh yes they are. But the plugin you have installed handles this specific use case.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt So how do I get it to work for all files, not only for files in a git repo?

Comment: @MahbubAlam what would you like to achieve? There are plugins that do not require git and add signs for those. For example https://github.com/mhinz/vim-signify or my https://github.com/chrisbra/changesPlugin But it really depends what you actually want to achieve and what you want the signs to show. You should clarify your question (and read the documentation of plugins you installed!)

Answer (score 1):

As @Christian Brabandt says, vim-gitgutter only shows signs for files which are tracked by git.  That's why it has "git" in the name.

If you have files in a git repo, and the files have unstaged changes, and you are not seeing signs, please open an issue on the plugin's repo.